# How to make the border blend with the background image

Tags: css

Here is what my active tabs look like:

[alt text http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/2783/picture22dl.png](http://img5.imageshack.us/img5/2783/picture22dl.png)

Notice that the bottom border (which connects the active tab to the content `<div>`) looks a little different from the rest of the tab.

What's going on here is that the tab background-color, tab border color, and the content `<div>` border color are all `#F58400`, but the active tab has a nice gradient-y background that looks like this:

http://img171.imageshack.us/img171/3368/uibginsetsoft30f584001x.png

Since the bottom of the gradient is lighter than `#F58400`, it clashes with the bottom border.

How can I fix this? Ideally I'd like the background image to start at the bottom of the border, though I suppose I could just change the border color to match the lightest color on the gradient.

Comment: you might also try asking this on http://doctype.com

Answer (score 1):

Make the tab see-through (have an alpha channel) so whatever you set the background to will show through it.

This also let's you change the color without loading a new image.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
#active_tab {border-bottom: 2px /* or whatever */ solid transparent; }
```

This might allow the image to show through. That or you might have to omit the border of the active_tab and position it closer to the lower content box.

---

**Edited:**

I realise that the border is technically outside of the element it, so it's unlikely that the the background will, or even should, show through the border. I also recall that there's a means by which the border can, in some way, be moved 'inside' the element's boundaries. But I can't remember the property.

I'm sorry that I can't be of more help.

Comment: I believe playing with margin and padding will change the border location?